# Reduce CPU wakeups by cinnamon and i915

Tags: graphics, cinnamon, power-management, laptop, i915

In order to reduce my notebook's power consumption I am using PowerTOP 2.5.

hardware: Thinkpad W540
os: Linux Mint 17.3 Rosa
kernel: 3.16.0-38-generic

I noticed that cinnamon and i915 are the primary causes for cpu wakeups:
[image: powertop]

Any idea how I could configure them differently so they cause less cpu wakeups?